# What do pivotX and pivotY mean in Android animations?

Tags: android, android-animation

These two terms occur in many places but what exactly do they mean in the context of Android animations?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The pivotX and pivotY is the central point of the animation.
So for example if you want to do Zoom In animation you can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

and the `android:pivotX="50%"` and `android:pivotY="50%"` will mean the zoom will be started from the center.

There is also a nice tutorial by android hive [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

Comment: can i change the `android:pivotY="50%"` or `android:pivotX="50%"` value in java ?

Comment: @medo I don't think you can modify it but you can create an animation with your desired pivot with ScaleAnimation constructor.

Comment: @NikoYuwono i found this `new ScaleAnimation(...);`